# pointerLockElement return null when called immediately after requestPointerLock() function

Tags: javascript, pointerlock

`PointerLockElement` returns null when called immediately after `requestPointerLock()` function

```js
domElement.onclick = () => { // requestPointerLock() needs to be called by user input

  domElement.requestPointerLock = domElement.requestPointerLock || domElement.mozRequestPointerLock;

  domElement.requestPointerLock();
  console.log(document.pointerLockElement || document.mozPointerLockElement); // return null

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestPointerLock):

> The Element.requestPointerLock() method lets you asynchronously ask for the pointer to be locked on the given element.

Asynchronous means, that you cannot call those lines after another:

```js
domElement.requestPointerLock();
document.pointerLockElement || document.mozPointerLockElement;
```

In the moment the second line is executed, the first statement might not be finished yet.

The docs also mention:

> To track the success or failure of the request, it is necessary to listen for the pointerlockchange and pointerlockerror events at the Document level.

Use an implementation as shown in the [pointerlockchange docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/pointerlockchange_event):

```js
document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', (event) => {
  console.log('Pointer lock changed');
});
```